# How to group by on a struct element and convert it back to struct with same schema

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

Spark 2.4.5
In my data frame, I have an array of struct and the array holds the snapshot of a field from time to time.

Now, I am looking for a way to have only the snapshots when the data has changed.

My schema is as below

```
root 
 |-- fee: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- updated_at: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- fee: float (nullable = true)
 |-- status: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- updated_at: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- status: string (nullable = true)
```

Existing output:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|fee                                                                     |status                                                                                       |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[[1584579671000, 12.11], [1584579672000, 12.11], [1584579673000, 12.11]]|[[1584579671000, Closed-A], [1584579672000, Closed-A], [1584579673000, Closed-B], [1584579674000, Closed], [1584579675000, Closed-A]]|
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

As the 'fee' column has not changed so it should have only one entry
As the status has changed a few times so the o/p would be [[1584579671000, Closed-A], [1584579673000, Closed-B], [1584579674000, Closed], [1584579675000, Closed-A]]
Note here the status 'Closed-A' appears twice.

Trying to get the below output:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|fee                     |status                                                                                        |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[[1584579671000, 12.11]]|[[1584579671000, Closed-A], [1584579673000, Closed-B], [1584579674000, Closed], [1584579675000, Closed-A]]|
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Note: Trying not to have a user-defined function.

Comment: @jxc Spark version 2.4.5

Comment: In your input Closed-A appears 3 times, what about this value - [1584579672000, Closed-A] ?

Answer (score 1):

Using Spark Dataframe APIs the above problem could be approached as; Add a monotonically increasing id to uniquely identify each record, explode and flatten the dataframe, group by fee and status separately (as per requirements), aggregate grouped datafarme by id to collect the struct, join both dataframe using id, id could be dropped in the final datafarme.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.explode
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.monotonically_increasing_id
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.collect_list
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.struct

val idDF = df.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id)

val explodeDf = idDF
  .select(col("id"), col("status"), explode(col("fee")).as("fee"))
  .select(col("id"), col("fee"), explode(col("status")).as("status"))

val flatDF = explodeDf.select(col("id"), col("fee.fee"), col("fee.updated_at").as("updated_at_fee"), col("status.status"), col("status.updated_at").as("updated_at_status"))

val feeDF = flatDF.groupBy("id", "fee").min("updated_at_fee")
val feeSelectDF = feeDF.select(col("id"), col("fee"), col("min(updated_at_fee)").as("updated_at"))
val feeAggDF = feeSelectDF.groupBy("id").agg(collect_list(struct("fee", "updated_at")).as("fee"))


val statusDF = flatDF.groupBy("id", "status").min("updated_at_status")
val statusSelectDF = statusDF.select(col("id"), col("status"), col("min(updated_at_status)").as("updated_at"))
val statusAggDF = statusSelectDF.groupBy("id").agg(collect_list(struct("status", "updated_at")).as("status"))

val finalDF = feeAggDF.join(statusAggDF, "id")
finalDF.show(10)
finalDF.printSchema()
```

Comment: thanks for the help but it seems the group by the function will not help. Example for entries [[1584579671000, Closed-A], [1584579673000, Closed-A], [1584579674000, Closed], [1584579675000, Closed-A]] the output need to be [[1584579671000, Closed-A], [1584579674000, Closed], [1584579675000, Closed-A]]